# Como retirar espaço em branco que aparece apenas quando reduzo a janela

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, parallax, fullscreen

Tenho o site dividido por varias seções na qual o background é uma imagem com efeito parallax, em ecrã inteiro o site aparece-me direito, mas caso reduza a janela aparece me uma tira branca no fundo do site, todas as outras seções funcionam com exceção do conteúdo, que desce para a seção posterior.

Segue o css que estou a aplicar:

```
body {
background-color: #fff;
font-family: 'Roboto';
line-height: 21px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #fff;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 0;   
float: none !important;    
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
padding-bottom: 0px!important;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

#home{
background:url('../imagens/background_home.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;   
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: block;    
}
#district{
  background: url('../imagens/background_2.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 fixed; /*background: url('../imagens/background_2.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%; */
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
top: 100%;
left: 0px;
display: block;
}

#local{
background: url('../imagens/background_3.jpg') no-repeat 50% 0 fixed; 
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
top: 100%;
left: 0px;
display: block;
}
```

segue o html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">      
<title>FoCAs</title>                
<meta name="description" content="foCAs">
<meta name="keywords" content="FEUP">       
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,100,300,700,300italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    
</head> 
<body data-spy="scroll" id="body" >         
        <div class="container" id="home" data-speed="6" data-type="background">
            <div calss="row logotipo">
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 logotipo"><img src="./imagens/logo_home.png" class="img-responsive img-center" ></div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <nav class="navbarhome">
                        <ul class="menu" id="navbarhome">
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#district">DISTRICT</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>               
                            <li><a href="#local" class="page-scroll">LOCAL ECOSSYSTEM</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>                  
                            <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">LIFE IN DISTRICT</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>                 
                            <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">AGENDA</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>                  
                            <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">USEFUL INFORMATION</a></li>
                            <li>|</li>                 
                            <li class="bandeiras"><a href="#"><img src="./imagens/pt_on.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"></a></li>
                            <li class="bandeiras"><a href="#"><img src="./imagens/uk_on.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- <div id="log">log</div>
        <div id="log2">log2</div> -->
    <section id="district" data-speed="6" data-type="background">   
        <div class="container-fluid">               
            <div class="row" id="menufixo">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="navbar-header menufixo">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menufixo">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars">MENU</i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" rel="home" href="#body" title="foCAs">
                        <img  src="./imagens/logo.png" class="img-responsive img-center"/>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#menufixo">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#district" class="page-scroll">DISTRICT</a></li>
                            <li><a>|</a></li>                                                   
                            <li><a href="#local" class="page-scroll">LOCAL ECOSSYSTEM</a></li>
                            <li><a>|</a></li>                   
                            <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">LIFE IN DISTRICT</a></li>
                            <li><a>|</a></li>                  
                            <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">AGENDA</a></li>
                            <li><a>|</a></li>                   
                            <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">USEFUL INFORMATION</a></li>
                            <li><a>|</a></li>                  
                            <li class="bandeirasF"><a href="#"><img src="./imagens/pt_on.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"></a></li>
                            <li class="bandeirasF"><a href="#"><img src="./imagens/uk_on.jpg" class="img-responsive img-center"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>                  
            </div>                          
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid conteudo">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 conteudo-central">

                        <section>
                            <p><h2>DISTRICT</h2></p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
                            <div class="google-maps">
                               <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d14285.097337914034!2d-8.594056737643658!3d41.1766014510367!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zNDHCsDEwJzQ2LjMiTiA4wrAzNicwOS41Ilc!5e0!3m2!1spt-PT!2spt!4v1437057105263" width="900" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class="blank"></div>
                        </section>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 conteudo-lateral">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 titulo-lateral">Contactos</div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong><br/>
                                tlf: 22 508 1497<br/>
                                @: <a href="mailto:porto@innovationdistrict.org">porto@innovationdistrict.org</a></p>
                                <p>
                                    Hórario:<br/>
                                    9h30-13h30<br/>
                                    14h30-17h00
                                </p>

                            </div>          
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>                                    
                </div>                          
            </div>                                  
        </div> <!-- ## FIM DO CONTAINER DISTRICT ## -->
    </section>  
    <section id="local" data-speed="6" data-type="background">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid conteudo">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 conteudo-central">

                        <section>
                            <p><h2>DISTRICT</h2></p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
                            <div class="google-maps">
                               <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d14285.097337914034!2d-8.594056737643658!3d41.1766014510367!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zNDHCsDEwJzQ2LjMiTiA4wrAzNicwOS41Ilc!5e0!3m2!1spt-PT!2spt!4v1437057105263" width="900" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class="blank"></div>
                        </section>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 conteudo-lateral">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 titulo-lateral">Contactos</div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong><br/>
                                tlf: 22 508 1497<br/>
                                @: <a href="mailto:porto@innovationdistrict.org">porto@innovationdistrict.org</a></p>
                                <p>
                                    Hórario:<br/>
                                    9h30-13h30<br/>
                                    14h30-17h00
                                </p>

                            </div>          
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>                                    
                </div>                          
            </div>                                  
        </div> <!-- ## FIM DO CONTAINER DISTRICT ## -->
    </section>




<!-- JS's -->
<scrit scr="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O resultado é este que apresento nas imagens seguintes:

### Ecrã completo:

[image: Imagem em ecra completo tudo ok]

### Ecrã reduzido

[image: imagem com ecra reduzido]

Aqui fica a imagem que mostra que mesmo sem a caixa, aquele espaço aparece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo online: http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~bonzinho

Comment: Por favor, apresente o código HTML que você possui para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Comment: Na imagem pode parecer que que é devido à caixa com o mapa, mas mesmo que as dimensões  mais pequenas da caixa aparece essa risca branca aumentando e diminuindo consoante o tamanho da janela :/

Comment: Isso acontece porque o tamanho do documento aumentou, mas a imagem de fundo tem um tamanho fixo, e não cobre toda a área.

Comment: mas se assim fosse o mesmo nao haveria de acontecer em fullscreen? se for assim como tu dizes, tens alguma dica para resolver?

Comment: @LaranjaMecânica, tente colocar teu código funcionando aqui no SO clicando no botão de _snippet_ `<>` ou no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), assim fica mais fácil pra quem for te ajudar.

Comment: aquilo nao ficou la muito bem, nunca usei o jsfidle, mas fica aqui o link https://jsfiddle.net/3y5p51p4/

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido,

era problema com o js do parallax que estava a fazer com que alterasse o background position para um valor negativo

Obrigado

Comment: -1: Forneça um exemplo de como corrigiu, pode ser util a outros usuários. - assim que editar +1 :)